# Align divs with each other and create columns inside a column

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to do a step bar (kinda) that must work with an undifined number os steps given by the backend. So far, I managed to create this

[image]

which is okay (some bars linking the circles would be great).
However, in a smaller screen I have a problem with the dates because the text splits into 2 lines.

[image]

**Is it possible to make those divs always aligned with each others?**
Another problem that I have is on the smaller screens... **I would like to put the text side-by-side with the icons.** For such thing I already defined 2 columns (col-xs-6) within the main div but its not working.

[image]

**UPDATE1:** Thanks to @prabesh-gouli I was able to solve one of the problems: getting stuff side-by-side. The problem with the dates remains (second image).

```js
calculateClasses(data: string): string {
  if (data) {
    return 'icon col-xs-6 activeStep';
    else
      return 'icon col-xs-6 inactiveStep';
  }
}

estados = [{
    texto: "Inscrito",
    data: "01/07/2020 12:00H"
  },
  {
    texto: "Atendido",
    data: "02/07/2020 12:00H"
  },
  {
    texto: "Em Processamento",
    data: "03/07/2020 12.00H"
  },
  {
    texto: "Aguarda Revisão",
    data: "04/07/2020 12.00H"
  },
  {
    texto: "Concluído",
    data: "05/07/2020 12.00H"
  },
  {
    texto: "Entregue",
    data: ""
  }
];
```

```css
.step {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.stepDate {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.stepText {
  word-wrap: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.activeStep::before {
  border: 2px solid #1678e9;
  background: #1678e9;
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e876";
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.inactiveStep::before {
  border: 2px solid #C5CAE9;
  background: #C5CAE9;
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "\e14c";
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .step {
    display: flex;
  }
  #stepInfo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: start;
  }
  .icon {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .inactiveStep::before {
    margin-right: 15%;
  }
  .activeStep::before {
    margin-right: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="step col-sm-4 col-md-2" *ngFor="let estado of estados">
    <div [ngClass]="calculateClasses(estado.data)"></div>
    <div id="stepInfo">
      <div class="stepText">{{ estado.texto }}</div>
      <div class="stepDate" *ngIf="estado.data">{{ estado.data }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or 4? because in bootstrap 4 there are no col-xs- classes. Also, the snippet is not working

Comment: Hi Erica. I'm using bootstrap 4.5.0. However, if I use col-6 instead of col-xs-6 thins get a little messed up. I don't know why it's not working here. I posted the code needed to show the problems

Comment: ok, but col-xs- classes are not defined in bootstrap 4 so they aren't doing anything unless you define them in your css. I have edited the snippet but it haven't been reviewed yet, maybe if you fix the code the community will be able to help you faster

Comment: it's ok you using bootstrap but do some edit and inject flex css too.

Comment: @Erica, I edited the code at the same time and I guess the system rejected your edition so please edit it again pls. I'm not very good with css and html (still learning :) ). Regarding the col-xs I guess it's working since on smaller screens everything gets stacked. Is it due to the d-flex class?

Comment: @PrabeshGouli can you explain it better? As I told Erica i'm still learning css/html

Comment: Please try this link. If you still got confused you can ping me https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: The error in the snippet seems to be about js: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 75,
  "colno": 26
}

Comment: @EricaT. I dont know how to fix thar error. That file is not mine. I guess its a SoF file that runs on the background

Comment: @PrabeshGouli thanks mate. I was able to fix one of the problems. How about the other? Do you have a solution?

Comment: i just saw the comment, what is other problem ? :)

Comment: Which one? Basically I had to work with the flex box. I made some changes that I do not remember now xD but it included defining some media queries. It's working and that is what it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PrabeshGouli I was able to fix my problems. The answer is the [flex box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) as he said. With that it's possible to define the flex-direction (column vs row) of the elements and set how the elements should be placed (justify-content). It took me some time to figure it out but with some trial and error I fixed my problems.